# how to delete filters from only few columns in the excel sheet not all of the columns using java apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have applied filters to the excel sheet columns A7 to M7 using the method
`sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A7:M7"));` but now I want to remove filters from the column J7,K7 and L7 but couldn't find any method in apache poi 3.17

```
for(int j=0;j<=12;j++)
    {
        if(j==9||j==10||j==11)
        {
            continue;   
        }
            sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(6,6, j, j));                                                               
    }
```

Comment: The `apache poi` cannot do what `Excel` itself does not provides. Each `Excel` sheet can only have **one** continuous autofilter range. But a `Excel` sheet may have multiple `Tables` (`XSSFTable`) where each may have it's own autofilter range.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a method present which excludes some of the columns from a range. But you can try by splitting the range based on the exclude columns. The MsExcel supports ranges with commas which will work here.

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A7:M7"));
```

The range can be changed to (if J7,K7 and L7 are excluded),

```
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A7:I7, M7:M7"));
```

Comment: Using what `Excel`version does this work? All `Excel` versions I know only support one autofilter range per sheet.

Comment: I did not test this. It is based on the ms office excel as function supports ranges with commas.

Comment: @AxelRichter if it is not going to work, I have to revisit my answer and suggest OP other alternatives or better solution.

Comment: @Shivam Pandey , Thanks for the response , but it didn't work i am getting "Invalid CellReference: I7, M7" as a exception....can you please assist

Comment: @Shivam Pandey , i am merging J7,K7,L7 and M7 to form a single cell and want to apply filter for it at the end which means to the M7 cell but the above method is applying for all JKL and M7 ....is there any method to delete the filters by specifying the cell range

Comment: @Preeti I will look into this and also as AxelRichter suggested here, it does not support more than an autofilter range per sheet.

Comment: @ShivamPandey please suggest a method supported in apache poi 3.17 to delete the filters using cell range as parameter